# Application container design

Tags: php, object-oriented

I'm putting together a simple application container for learning purposes, and I would like to hear how you see this code. The application is the main class that will contain services, configuration and other related stuff.

I have identified 3 position where I can't decide on the design:

1. Each application should be supplied with configuration array. The configuration will be loaded automatically, so some class has to deal with it. Does `Kernel` class is the right place to put it? The `Kernel` class is intended to contain some common functions, like `getRootPath()`. Does it starts to violate SRP in this case?
2. Does `getType()` look like the right way to define type of application? Should i make it abstract or provide some default type in parent class?
3. Overall, does `Kernel` class fits the purpose of creating application instances and supplying required configuration and calling `ready()` on application?

```
namespace App;

interface Executable {
    public function run();
    public function ready();
}

abstract class Application implements Executable {
    const TYPE_WEB = 'web';
    const TYPE_CLI = 'cli';

    /**
    * Application name
    * @var string
    */
    protected $name = '';

    /**
    * Application configuration
    * @var array
    */
    protected $config = [];

    public function __construct($name, array $config=[]) {
        $this -> name = $name;
        $this -> config = $config;
    }

    public function ready() {
        // Application is ready, register services here...
    }

    public function run() {
        // Execute application lifecycle
    }
}

class WebApplication extends Application {
    public function getType() {
        return self::TYPE_WEB;
    }
}

class ConsoleApplication extends Application {
    public function getType() {
        return self::TYPE_CLI;
    }
}

abstract class Kernel {
    /**
    * Instantiated applications
    * @var Executable[]
    */
    private static $apps = [];

    /**
    * Creates new application
    * @param string $name Application name
    * @param string $type Application class
    */
    public static function createApp($name, $type) {
        /* Some validations skipped */

        $app = self::$apps[$name] = new $type($name, self::loadConfiguration($name));
        $app -> ready();

        return $app;
    }

    private static function loadConfiguration($name) {
        /* Load configuration from files and from multiple places */
        return [
            'key' => 'value'
        ];
    }

    public static function getRootPath() {
        // Return path to document root
    }
}

/**************/
App\Kernel::createApp('test', 'WebApplication') -> run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some opinionated advice:

I don't see why having two separate class, so I merge Kernel into App and rename it "AppKernel".

- Then, I removed the "ready" method to replace it by the "create" from Kernel.
- You don't need the "getType" function since your classes already define a "type"
- I don't really understand why you want to keep a reference to your application's instances, so I remove it.
- For me you should load the configuration from the outside with a dedicated "configuration" object.

EDIT: I added a method to create "singleton" application, I think this method will work but I am not 100% sure, so try it before.

All this transformation lead to something like this:

```
<?php
namespace App;

interface Executable
{
    public function run();
    public function ready();
}

class Configuration
{
    public static function load() {
        return [
            'key' => 'value'
        ];
    }
}

abstract class AppKernel implements Executable
{
    /**
     * Application name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = '';
    private static $instances = [];
    /**
     * Application configuration
     * @var array
     */
    protected $config = [];

    protected function __construct($name, Configuration $config)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public static function create($name, Configuration $config)
    {
        if(!isset(static::$instance[$name]))
           static::$instance[$name] = new static($name, $config);

        return static::$instance[$name];
    }

    public function run()
    {

    }
}

class WebApplication extends AppKernel {}

class ConsoleApplication extends AppKernel {}

ConsoleApplication::create('name', configuration::load())->run();
```

Comment: Haven't thought about separate configuration object. This simplifies the kernel class. The reason why there is reference is to have only single application instance.

Comment: I edit the code, to add a singleton management

Comment: Yes this looks like the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on a singleton instance. Usage of a singleton can make testing extremely hard, as it is impossible to maintain separate instances. You should use another class outside the AppKernel, which tracks the number of available instances.